# Keeper Action Card Reuse in Mansions of Madness

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Some Keeper Action cards in MoM specifically state "This card can be used only once per Keeper turn." Other specifically state that a card may be used a number of times - once per monster on the board, or some such.

But most of the cards are not specific. Does this mean they can be used multiple times per Keeper turn by default?

For example - the Raise Dead card allows the Keeper to spend 1 Threat to place a corpse token or spend 2 Threat to replace a corpse with a Zombie.

- Can I as Keeper spend 3 Threat to place the corpse and replace it with the Zombie?
- If so, can I keep doing that as long as I have enough Threat to spend? (Subject to the limited number of Zombie figures, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**,

Unless restricted by the card, the Keeper is only restricted by his available threat in terms of using the same Keeper Action multiple times.

See [this errata](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/633474/uncontrollable-urges-officially-fixed) by the designer on BoardGameGeek.  It's obvious that the errata is meant to limit the usage.  If the default was once/turn, there would be no need for the errata.